# Intriguing Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that:

> $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {\sqrt 2 n^{\left(n-\frac 12\right)}}{n!}\left(\frac {(2\sqrt[n] {n} -1)^n}{n^2}\right)^{ \frac {n\left(n-\frac 12\right)}{\ln^2 n}}=\sqrt {\frac {e}{\pi}}$$

My method:

Properties I am going to use :

1)Stirling's approximation:$$n!\sim\sqrt {2\pi n} \left(\frac ne\right)^n$$

2)Property 2 : $$\sqrt[n] {n}\sim 1+\frac {\ln n}{n}+\frac{\ln^2 n}{2n^2}$$

3)Property 3: For all continuous and differentiable functions $f,g$ (In their domain respectively),  if $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=0$ then for large enough $x$ we have $$(1+g(x))^{f(x)}\sim e^{f(x)\cdot g(x)}$$

Using Stirling's approximation we get $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^n}{\sqrt{\pi} n}\left(\frac {\displaystyle (2\sqrt[n]{n} -1)^n}{n^2}\right)^{\frac {n\left(n-\frac 12\right)}{\ln^2n}}$$

Using Property 2 we get $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^n}{\sqrt {\pi} n}\left(\frac { \left(1+\frac {2\ln n}{n}+\frac{\ln^2n}{n^2}\right)^n}{n^2}\right)^{\frac {n\left(n-\frac 12\right)}{\ln^2n}}$$

And using the property 3 we get $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^n}{\sqrt{\pi} n} \displaystyle \frac {e^{\frac {n(2n-1)}{\ln n}}\cdot e^{ \left(n-\frac 12\right)}}{ n^{\frac {n(2n-1)}{\ln^2 n}}}$$

Using that $$n^{\frac {n(2n-1)}{\ln^2 n}}=e^{\frac {n(2n-1)}{\ln n}}$$

Using this alongwith previous results we get $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^n}{\sqrt{\pi} n} \displaystyle \frac {e^{\frac {n(2n-1)}{\ln n}}}{e^{ \frac {n(2n-1)}{\ln n}}}\cdot e^{ \left(n-\frac 12\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^{2n}}{\sqrt{e\pi} n}$$

Which  clearly doesn't converge.Can someone please point out my mistake in above working. Also some new suggestions to solve this question will be quite beneficial.

Comment: The error arises when you substitute $1+\frac {\ln n}{n}+\frac{\ln^2 n}{2n^2}$ for  $\sqrt[n] {n}$. While that would normally be a valid substitution, you are raising that to a power dependent on $n$, so the error gets "compounded".

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated Ok Thanks, Can you please provide some suggestion to prove original limit

Comment: Unless there is a very good reason, we prefer not to arbitrarily delete good content: the answers could well help other users in the future.

Comment: @robjohn Oh sorry about that. Actually I solved it perfectly after automaticallyGenerated pointed out my mistake. So as the question was already solved by me, and at that moment there were no answers so I thought to delete the question. But since you have also answered the question ,its well and good now. I hope this question helps in any way to the future readers . Thanks for the advice..

Comment: It is perfectly fine to post answers for your own questions. In fact, that may help those who have looked at your question and want to know how to solve it.

Comment: @robjohn Actually my method is nearly same to yours so there will be no point in posting my method, because your post is elaborated enough to explain the proof...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can start with
$$
\log\left(n^{1/n}\right)=\frac{\log(n)}n
$$
and use the power series for $e^x$ to get
$$
2n^{1/n}-1=1+2\frac{\log(n)}n+\frac{\log(n)^2}{n^2}+\frac{\log(n)^3}{3n^3}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)^4}{n^4}\right)
$$
The power series for $\log(1+x)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(2n^{1/n}-1\right)
&=\overbrace{2\frac{\log(n)}n+\frac{\log(n)^2}{n^2}+\frac{\log(n)^3}{3n^3}}^x\overbrace{-2\frac{\log(n)^2}{n^2}-2\frac{\log(n)^3}{n^3}}^{-x^2/2}\overbrace{+\frac83\frac{\log(n)^3}{n^3}}^{x^3/3}\\
&=2\frac{\log(n)}n-\frac{\log(n)^2}{n^2}+\frac{\log(n)^3}{n^3}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)^4}{n^4}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Multiply by $n$ and use the power series for $e^x$ where $x=-\frac{\log(n)^2}n+\frac{\log(n)^3}{n^2}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)^4}{n^3}\right)$:
$$
\left(2n^{1/n}-1\right)^n=n^2\left(1-\frac{\log(n)^2}n+\frac{\log(n)^4+2\log(n)^3}{2n^2}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)^6}{n^3}\right)\right)
$$
Divide by $n^2$ and use the power series for $\log(1+x)$:
$$
\log\left(\frac{\left(2n^{1/n}-1\right)^n}{n^2}\right)=-\frac{\log(n)^2}n+\frac{\log(n)^3}{n^2}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)^6}{n^3}\right)
$$
Multiply by $\frac{n\left(n-\frac12\right)}{\log^2(n)}$, use the power series for $e^x$, and apply Stirling's Formula to get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt2n^{\left(n-\frac 12\right)}}{n!}\left(\frac{\left(2n^{1/n}-1\right)^n}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n\left(n-\frac12\right)}{\log^2(n)}}
&=\frac{\sqrt2n^{\left(n-\frac 12\right)}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\,n^ne^{-n}}ne^{\frac12-n}\left(1+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)^4}n\right)\right)\\
&=\sqrt{\frac e\pi}\left(1+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)^4}n\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt2n^{\left(n-\frac 12\right)}}{n!}\left(\frac{\left(2n^{1/n}-1\right)^n}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n\left(n-\frac12\right)}{\log^2(n)}}=\sqrt{\frac e\pi}
$$